# How to make a style based on a resource that is different from StaticResource

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary, basedon

I have a window which has a ResourceDictionary in Resources.
I made a CheckBox style which is based on the one that is defined in the ResourceDictionary.
What is more, I'd like to make a RadioButton based on a ToggleButton style, which is NOT based on the one that is defined in the ResourceDictionary.
I used ControlTemplate as shown in the following code, but in this case, TemplateBinding is necessary for all the properties involved.
Is there a better way to realize my purpose without using ControlTemplate?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/theme;component/BasicTheme.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>

    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}">
            <!-- Several style setters -->
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="Edit"/>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ToggleTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource Edit}"
                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                      IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <CheckBox/>
    <RadioButton Template="{DynamicResource ToggleTemplate}"/>

</Grid>
```

The following code didn't work properly.

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="Edit"/>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource Edit}" x:Key="ToggleStyle"/>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource ToggleStyle}"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: "Is there a better way to realize my purpose?" is not really a question that we can answer. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Glen Thomas Thank you for your advice. I revised my question. I'd like to realize my purpose without using ControlTemplate.

Comment: I've read your question 3 times and I still have no idea what you are asking. Could you clarify your question a bit? I struggle with "I'd like to make a RadioButton based on a ToggleButton style" - What does that even mean? You want to style a RadioButton to look like a ToggleButton, but not use the style included in that dictionary, nor use a ControlTemplate?

Comment: @user3690202 Yes, you are right. I want a style for a RadioButton in which it looks like a ToggleButton, but not use the style included in the resource dictionary. I'd like to realize this without using ControlTemplate.

Comment: No, it is not possible. If you want to dramatically change how the RadioButton looks then you must replace it's template. It's as simple as that.